# Importing UTF-8 text file (with Italian accents) in R

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to import into R a text file, saved with **TextWrangler** as Unicode (UTF-8) and Unix(LF)

Here is the code I am using:

```
scan("Testi/PIRANDELLOsigira.txt", fileEncoding='UTF-8', what=character(), sep='\n')
```

I got the following warning:

```
 Read 6 items
 Warning message:
 In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
 invalid input found on input connection 'Testi/PIRANDELLOsigira.txt'
```

and a vector that stops at the first accented character.

Answer (score 1):

first change your locale from Italy to English

```
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")
```

Then you can read the data with italian encoding

```
df_ch <- read.table("test.utf8",
                     sep=",",
                     header=TRUE, 
                     encoding=" Italian", 
                     )
```

if you want to only read the data with UTF-8 encoding
you can simply use the following

```
yourdf <- read.table(" path to your data.utf8",
                        sep=",",
                        header=TRUE, 
                        encoding="UTF-8", 
                        )
```